# C/C++ MPI: Cascading MPI_BCasts is MPI_Barrier needed?

Tags: c++, c, mpi

i have a question regarding cascading MPI_Bcast calls, i want to know if there is anything to keep in mind when wanting to distribute different data blocks from changing send threads to all other threads right after each other.

Imagine like this:

```
double buff=12345; // value is not important for this example
for (i=0; i<nthreads; i++) {// loop over all threads
    MPI_BCast(&buff, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // the i-th threads sends all other receive
    // some, but not all threads do something with the data
    if (threadid > i) {
        // do something that can need much more time on some threads than on others
    }
}
```

I hope this example code explains the situation. Basically there is a for loop over all threads and in each iteration a different sending thread is used, the possible problem here is, that each thread take a different amount of time to get to MPI_Bcast again. Is it possible to have the sending thread allready there while some receiving threads are maybe still receiving from the last sender?
Do i need a MPI_Barrier here or can i cascade as much Bcasts as i want as long it is clear that each call is reached by every thread once?

edit: And what is when there is no loop over all threads but some other way to interate through a list of sending threads, so that it is possible to have the same sendign thread multiple times in a row?
Is it possible then to mix something, maybe the receiving threads only waiting for informations from the thread with id i do not differentiate between the first and second or one of the following Bcasts from that thread?

Comment: Good MPI implementations should not have any problems with your code as long as all ranks call `MPI_Bcast` using the same sequence of root ranks (as it the case with your code).

Comment: Is this also the case when there a multiple calls of Bcast with the same sending thread? I could imagine that there are problems when bcast works like a "fire and forget" method for the sending thread, which means, the sending thread send its data, then proceed further while the other threads are still receiving and maybe some of them still not have reached the Bcast call. In this scenario it could be possible for the sending thread to reach the next bcast and starts sending new data before some of the other threads reached even the first bcast.

Comment: Broadcasts are implemented using deterministic algorithms. Two consecutive broadcasts will **not** interact with each other given a good MPI implementation, even if some of the processes are still executing the first broadcast. Note that Open MPI, MPICH, Intel MPI, MVAPICH, and many other fall into the "good MPI" category in that case.

Comment: Thanks, is this generally the case for methods of "good MPI" implementations, like for example the MPI_allgather and MPI_reduce methods? Can they be cascaded with MPI_bcasts and each other without having an MPI_barrier in between?

Comment: As long as you keep the order of all collective calls over a particular communicator the same in all ranks - yes.